# Backbone set save (PUT) request with different URL endpoints

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

In backbone, and on server I have put request with different endpoints after id (api/order/ID/call and api/order/ID/status). I need to set these depending on different actions obviously. I got the status working by extending/overriding the models sync:

```
sync: function(method, model, options){

    if (method == 'PUT' || method == 'update') {

        model.url = '/venues/orders/' + model.id + '/status';

        var jsonData            = {};
            jsonData.staffid    = 1;
            jsonData.groupid    = 0;
            jsonData.statusid   = this.get('status.statusid');

        //if the options url is set use that otherwise use /status
        if( options.url ){
            model.url = options.url;
        }

        options.data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    }

    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
 }
```

I have a call function that set's the options url :

```
CallToBar: function(el){

    log("CallToBar Action");

    el.preventDefault();
    el.stopPropagation();

    var target = $(el.currentTarget);

    target.text('Calling...');
    var that = this;

    this.model.save({}, {
        url: '/venues/orders/' + this.model.id + '/call',
        data: '',
        success: function(){
            target.text('Called');

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {

                if( !$(this.el).find('.additional-options').hasClass('hide') ){
                    that.orderClicked();
                }
                target.text('Call to bar');

            }, 1500);
        }

    }); 

},
```

I want to have the ability to attached different endpoints to urls ideally with sync/save/set

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question yesterday. Have you considered using PATCH? http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save . This allows you to have a single end point, but allows you to only pass the attributes you want to update? e.g. model.save(attr, {patch: true});

Comment: PATCH isn't really want i need has the calls are just triggers i don't want to change attr. Also PATCH isn't currently configured on server.